# Writing simple equations in Octave

Tags: octave

Imagine I want to define a function in Octave `z(var1, var2) = a(var1) + b(var1) + c(var2) + d(var2) + const`. Prior to this definition, I would like to define all the neccessary functions, something like: `a(var1) = var1^2 + const`, `b(var1) = cos(var1)`, `c(var) = sqrt(var2 - const)` etc. Later in time, I add all those functions and form the final one, `z` function. Afterwards, I'd like to get partial derivatives of the function `z` in respect to `var1` and `var2`.

So far, my only concern is defining the functions above to work as i imagined; is it possible and how ?

Comment: Symbolic partial derivatives or finite differences are OK?

Comment: Since I am using Octave to test a complex equation that will be minimized by gradient descent algorithm in Java, seems like finite differences is the answer. Also, is Octave the tool to do it or should i transfer to Matlab ?

Comment: MATLAB is probably going to be a little faster, although Octave is definitely catching up. Personally, I find both a little awkward compared to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [function handles](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Function-Handles.html) and [anonymous functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Anonymous-Functions.html):

```
a = @(x) x^2 + c1;
b = @cos;
c = @(x) sqrt(x - c2);
d = @exp;
```

`b` and `d` are handles to existing functions. You can call them as regular functions using `b(...)` or `d(...)`. `a` and `c` are anonymous functions. They provide the argument list and definition of the handle right there in the assignment, somewhat like Python's lambdas. You could do something like `b = @(x) cos(x)`, but there is really no point since there are no additional operations necessary.

Now you can do

```
z = @(x, y) a(x) + b(x) + c(y) + d(y) + c3;
```

The alternative is to write separate m-files for each function, which I am assuming you would like to avoid.

Using the function, for example to take partial derivatives, is now fairly straightforward. Function handles are called just like any other builtin or m-file-defined function:

```
(z(x + delta, y) - z(x - delta, y)) / (2 * delta)
```

**Update**

Just for fun, I ran the following script (using Octave 3.4.3 on Red Hat 6.5):

```
octave:1> c1 = -100;
octave:2> c2 = -10;
octave:3> c3 = 42;
octave:4> a = @(x) x^2 + c1;
octave:5> b = @cos;
octave:6> c = @(x) sqrt(x - c2);
octave:7> d = @exp;
octave:8> z = @(x, y) a(x) + b(x) + c(y) + d(y) + c3;
octave:9> [X, Y] = meshgrid([-10:0.1:10], [-10:0.1:10]);
octave:10> surf(X, Y, z(X, Y));
```

The result is not especially interesting, but it does demonstrate the effectiveness of this technique:

[image]

Here is an [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/JLPYrU) link to play with.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, looks pretty good at first glance, I will test it when i come home and mark it as correct if I succeed :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit @MadPhysicist. That plot was plain ugly, hahah. You must be using a *really* old version of Octave?!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou. I am. The new plot looks quite nice.

Comment: Yeah, octave is looking very good indeed these days. I prefer it to matlab. Especially for plots, I find they look much nicer! I'm using it exclusively for all the figures in my thesis.